# Struts 2 iterator tag onchange issue

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I am using Struts 2.1.6. I am having an issue while trying to set the value of an attribute using `onchange` event within the `<s:iterator>` tag.

```
<s:iterator value="myList" status="rowStatus">      
 <tr>
    <td><s:textfield name="myList[%{#rowStatus.index}].abc" value="%{model[#rowStatus.index].abc}"  onchange="myList[%{#rowStatus.index}].changeFlag = "true"/></td>
    <td><s:textfield name="myList[%{#rowStatus.index}].changeFlag" value="%{model[#rowStatus.index].changeFlag}" /></td>
 </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

The list `myList` has multiple objects and if there is a change to the value of `abc` attribute of any particular row then I am trying to set the value of the `changeFlag` to `true`. However it doesn't work.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `onchange` attribute in the [`s:textfield`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/textfield.html) tag is

### Set the HTML `onchange` attribute on rendered HTML element

and the rendered html element is `<input type="text">`. For this element the `onchange` attribute defines a javascript function to handle the event. So you can create a function `doChange()`. But before you need to add `id` attribute

### HTML id attribute

this allows to locate element in the document by `id`.

```jsp
<s:iterator value="myList" status="rowStatus">      
 <tr>
    <td><s:textfield id="myList[%{#rowStatus.index}].abc" name="myList[%{#rowStatus.index}].abc" value="%{model[#rowStatus.index].abc}"  onchange="doChange('myList[%{#rowStatus.index}].changeFlag')"/></td>
    <td><s:textfield id="myList[%{#rowStatus.index}].changeFlag" name="myList[%{#rowStatus.index}].changeFlag" value="%{model[#rowStatus.index].changeFlag}" /></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
<script>
function doChange(dest) {
 document.getElementById(dest).value = 'true';
} 
</script>
```

---

P.S.: The version of Struts that you are using is too old (2.1.6). You should know how to get the newer version. See [How to know a version of Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35985333/573032).